# How to catch Span Id attribute

Tags: php

here it is my html code:

```
<td>
          <span id="ctl00_mainContent_DisplayEventSummaryBlock_DisplayEventRepeater_ctl00_Athlete1ResultScore">9.63</span>
</td>
```

I'm trying to use this PHP code:

```
$score_man = $result_man->getElementByTagName('span');
$Score = trim($score_man->getAttribute('id')->plaintext);
```

where `$result_man` is a variable catching previously from a `tr.line_results` object.
But I didn't get 9.63, which is the item I need.

What is it incorrect?

Comment: What *do* you get from that?

Comment: You should tag the library you are using here, simple html dom? I'd think you wouldn't ask for the `id` because the `id` will be `ctl00_mainContent_DisplayEventSummaryBlock_DisplayEventRepeater_ctl00_Athlete1ResultScore`.

Comment: your html is not clear plz provide html in detail, and mention what are you using for dom parsing?

Comment: Why not use `getElementById('ctl00_mainContent_DisplayEventSummaryBlock_DisplayEventRepeater_ctl00_Athlete1ResultScore')`?  Then `$Score = (string) $score_man;` should return the contents.

Comment: This is the html page:

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution in PHP:

```
$string = <<<XML
<td>
    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_DisplayEventSummaryBlock_DisplayEventRepeater_ctl00_Athlete1ResultScore">9.63</span>
</td>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_mainContent_DisplayEventSummaryBlock_DisplayEventRepeater_ctl00_Athlete1ResultScore"]');

echo $result[0];
```